# how to make pointer like UI on horizontal histogram bar?

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-seekbar

I want to make UI as shown in the below image, I use `seekbar` type of thing or any suggestions for this type of UI?

(Note: The progress value is dynamic)

[image: example of progress bar UI showing "Only need 20" and 80/100 (80%)]

Comment: This [Library](https://github.com/warkiz/IndicatorSeekBar) has a lot of features including your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, will use it